# Write VLOOKUP to each row in a column - openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Trying to apply a vlookup formula to each row in a given column ('B') with the code below;

```
import openpyxl

path = 'test.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws2 = wb['Sheet2']

for eachrow in ws2['B']:
    print(eachrow)
    openpyxl.cell.value = '=VLOOKUP(B{0},Sheet1!A:A,1,0)'

print(ws2['B2'].value)
```

the `print(eachrow)` line gives me all the rows individually as I want them but the next line does not update the values with the provided VLOOKUP string.

`print(ws2['B2'].value)` returns the value `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `openpyxl.cell.value = '=VLOOKUP(B{0},Sheet1!A:A,1,0)'` is not doing what you think it's doing. You already have a reference to the cell; `eachrow`. Instead, use:

`eachrow.value = '=VLOOKUP(B{0},Sheet1!A:A,1,0)'`

However, openpyxl does not evaluate excel formulas, so your call to print will only print `=VLOOKUP(B{0},Sheet1!A:A,1,0)'`. If you want to evaluate the formula you could look at using `xlwings`

Comment: ah, i understand. thank you!